# Excel.Range object not disposing so not Closing the Excel process

Tags: office-interop

I am banging my head since hours to dispose the Excel.Range Object creating by the statement below. I Have checked almost all the Discussions regarding it on Stack Overflow.

```
oSheet.Range("A1", "H1").Merge()
```

When i comment out this line Excel Application closes successfully. But when i use this line it creates the Excel.Range object which is not disposing of by GC. Can anyone please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do nested calls like that, instead change it to be something like:

```
Dim r As Object = oSheet.Range("A1", "H1")
r.Merge()
```

Then r can be disposed properly by a:

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(r)
```

And then you can reuse the variable if you want:

```
r = oSheet.Cells(TitleRow3, 1)
' do something with r
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(r)
r = 'get a new range from somewhere
' do something with r
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(r)
...
```

Comment: But i am using too many instances of oSheet.Range with different parameters Can't i use some general solution for creating oSheet.Range object at one time and then use it for rest operations?

Comment: @Irfan: Not sure if I understand the issue, but you could just reuse the same variable, just remember to release it before you assign a new range to it.

Comment: How can i teckle oSheet.Cells(TitleRow3, 1) because its also returning the same Excel.Range object

Comment: @Irfan: I'm still not sure if I understand what you're asking, but I amended my answer to try to show what I think you want to do.

Comment: @ho1.Thanks that was exactly i was looking into.

Comment: how are you? i am stuck up in the font class now. The font class object is not destroying. oFont=oCells(TitleRow3, 1).font, oFont.Bold=true, Marshall.ReleaseComObject(oFont), its not working properly.