# Cordinates of a shape in PowerPoint (c#)

Tags: c#, coordinates, powerpoint, shapes, points

I want to get the coordinates of a PowerPoint shape.

here is my c# implementation

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Application myPPT = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide curSlide = myPPT.ActiveWindow.View.Slide;

foreach (Shape current in curSlide.Shapes)
{
   Debug.Print(current.Type.ToString());              

   foreach (ShapeNode n in current.Nodes)
   {
      double x = n.Points[1, 1];
      double y = n.Points[1, 2];

      Debug.Print("X: " + x);
      Debug.Print("Y: " + y);
    }
}
```

This works fine for a "freehand"-shape, but not for the pre-installed ones (like rectangle, big arrow, star, ...) there I get error COMException.

Has anyone an idea how to implement that and access the points of a shape ?

Comment: What part of the VB.net code doesn't work? Did you convert that to C# beforehand? Show the C# you generated and describe a specific problem we can help you debug.

Comment: here is my C# Code:
it bugs on line "double x".
COMExcepton (HRESULT: 0x800A01A8)

foreach (Shape current in curSlide.Shapes)
{
   foreach (ShapeNode n in current.Nodes)
   {
      double x = n.Points(1, 1);
      double y = n.Points(1, 2);
   }
}

Comment: Your error code helps a lot. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081960/runtime-comexception-unhandeled

Answer (score 0):

I tried numerous ways and always ended up with the HRESULT: 0x800A01A8 error.

A workaround was to export shape as an image and use AForge to determine the edges of this image. Not pretty but did the work. I haven't find-tuned the code below to handle diffs in transformation and offsets.

```
    static List<Tuple<float,float>> ShapeToPoints(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape shape)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Temp\bpmimg\Test1.png";
        if (File.Exists(path))
            File.Delete(path);
        List<Tuple<float, float>> points = new List<Tuple<float, float>>();

        try
        {
            //Shape.Export is an internal method, but we access it via reflection this way
            var args = new object[] { path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpShapeFormat.ppShapeFormatPNG, 0, 0, Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpExportMode.ppRelativeToSlide };
            shape.GetType().InvokeMember("Export", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, shape, args); // Export to file on disk
            // locating objects
            BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
            blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
            blobCounter.MinHeight = 5;
            blobCounter.MinWidth = 5;

            //Important that the dispose is called so that the temp-file cleanup File.Delete doesn't crash due to locked file
            using (System.Drawing.Bitmap image = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(path))
            {
                blobCounter.ProcessImage(image);
            }
            Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();

            SimpleShapeChecker shapeChecker = new SimpleShapeChecker();
            if (blobs.Length != 1)
            {
                //Unexpected number of blobs
                return null;
            }
            var blob = blobs[0];

            List<IntPoint> edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blob);

            List<IntPoint> untransformedPoints;
            // use the shape checker to extract the corner points
            if (!shapeChecker.IsConvexPolygon(edgePoints, out untransformedPoints))
            {
                IConvexHullAlgorithm hullFinder = new GrahamConvexHull();
                untransformedPoints = hullFinder.FindHull(edgePoints);
            }
            var untransformedWidth = untransformedPoints.Max(p => p.X);
            var untransformedHeight = untransformedPoints.Max(p => p.Y);
            var widthRatio = untransformedWidth / shape.Width;//How many time bigger is the image-based figure than the shape figure
            var heightRatio = untransformedHeight / shape.Height;//How many time bigger is the image-based figure than the shape figure

            points = untransformedPoints.Select(p => new Tuple<float, float>(shape.Left + p.X / widthRatio, shape.Top + p.Y / heightRatio)).ToList();//Transform
        }
        finally
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
                File.Delete(path);
        }
        return points;
    }
```